# Create comma separated string from portion of strings in C# List

Tags: c#

I have a C# List that I want to create a comma separate string. I've found other answers on SO that deal with this, but my particular case I want to only use a portion of the values in the List to create the string.

If my List contained these values:

"Foo"
"Bar"
"Car"

and I wanted to create a string

```
Foo, Bar and Car.
```

I could use this code:

```
string.Format("{0} and {1}.", 
              string.Join(", ", myList.Take(myList.Count - 1)), 
              myList.Last());
```

However, my list is actual formed of jSON values like so

```
{ Name = "Foo" }
{ Name = "Bar" }
{ Name = "Car" }
```

So the above code results in:

```
{ Name = "Foo" }, { Name = "Bar" } and { Name = "Car" }.
```

How would I construct the string such that I only use the `Foo`, `Bar` and `Car` values in the list?

**Update**

Thanks to @StevePy, this is what I ended up with:

```
string.Format("{0} and {1}.", 
              string.Join(", ", myList.Select(x => x.Name).ToList().Take(myList.Count - 1)), 
              myList.Select(x => x.Name).ToList().Last());
```

Comment: Is your list a List<string> and each string is of the type "{ Name = "Foo" }" ?

Comment: so what's the actual output that you need? will you include `and` to your json response?

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409890/formatting-a-string-using-values-from-a-generic-list-by-linq

Comment: You can optimize that solution a bit for the last item by using `myList.Last().Name` to avoid re-listing the items. Or probably a bit better: `myList[myList.Count -1].Name` Not as suscinct, but I think .Last() still iterates over the entire set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq should help.

```
var nameList = myList.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to operate with strings, just grab the necessary part of each string with, for example, [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) and [String.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx) methods:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string> { 
    "{ Name = \"Foo\" }",
    "{ Name = \"Bar\" }",
    "{ Name = \"Car\" }"
};

var temp = myList.Select(x =>
    {
        int index = x.IndexOf("\"") + 1;
        return x.Substring(index, x.LastIndexOf("\"") - index);
    })
    .ToList();

string result = string.Format("{0} and {1}.",
                              string.Join(", ", temp.Take(myList.Count - 1)),
                              temp.Last());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `JsonConvert.toString` to get the value of your list item, or if you used a json serialization, you could use the JsonConvert.Deserialization

Comment: You could probably provide some code example for this to worth being an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I built a method that will do this for you:

```
static string ConvertToMyStyle(List<string> input)
{
    string result = "";

    foreach(string item in input)
    {
        if(input.IndexOf(item) != input.ToArray().Length-1)
            result += item + ", ";
        else
            result += "and " + item + ".";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this handles the single item case

```
protected string FormatWithOxfordCommas(List<string> reasons)
        {
            string result = "";
            if (reasons.Count == 1)
                result += reasons[0];
            else
            {
                foreach (string item in reasons)
                {
                    if (reasons.IndexOf(item) != reasons.Count - 1)
                        result += item + ", ";
                    else
                        result += "and " + item + ".";
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```